# Where can I get a complete list of all multi-byte functions for PHP?

Tags: php, multibyte, mbstring

Where can I get a complete list of all multi-byte functions for PHP?  I need to go through my application and switch the non MB string functions to the new mb functions.

Comment: do I need to bother doing this?  What would the consequnces bt for me to leave my DB utf-8 and not use the mb_string stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

https://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=mb

https://www.php.net/mbstring

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php

Answer (score 2):

And for the "and switch the non MB string functions to the new mb functions" part of the question: You might be interested in http://php.net/mbstring.overload:

> mbstring supports a 'function overloading' feature which enables you to add multibyte awareness to such an application without code modification by overloading multibyte counterparts on the standard string functions. For example, mb_substr() is called instead of substr() if function overloading is enabled. This feature makes it easy to port applications that only support single-byte encodings to a multibyte environment in many cases.

Comment: It is not recommended to use the function overloading option in the per-directory context, because it's not confirmed yet to be stable enough in a production environment and may lead to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You could use libraries that extends the main multibyte functions, like:
http://code.google.com/p/mbfunctions/

For mb_trim or mb_strtr, ie.